# Issue with android.support.v7.appcompat lib

Tags: android, ant, compilation

I am getting this error: `package android.support.v7.appcompat does not exist`. I am using `ant`.  Brought up `Android SDK Manager widget`, and see, `Extras - Android Support Repository` which I installed but noted that it installs jars from `extras/android/m2repository`, `however`, I need the `jars` installed from `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`.  Don't see how to get these installed via `Android SDK Manager widget`.  Am I not seeing it in the widget?  If not via `Android SDK Manager widget`, is there a way via command line?  TIA.

Comment: Ant/Eclipse is no longer supported. You should switch to Android Studio/Gradle if you want to use the newest version of the Support Library.

Comment: Thanks much ianhanniballake.  Do you recommend one over the other (Studio vs. Gradle?). Been avoiding IDE's like the plague, but it seems I have no choice now.

Comment: Actually, the whole point of Gradle is that you use the exact same build system whether you're in the IDE (Android Studio) or on the command line and get the exact same results. If you're more happy to only use the command line, you can most definitely forgo Android Studio entirely and use Gradle directly.

Comment: Let me get this straight.  Gradle is not an IDE then, but is strictly command line driven?

Comment: Right, Gradle is just a command line tool. It just happens to be that Android Studio uses Gradle to compile Android projects (unlike Eclipse, which used a totally _different_ build system than ant to compile projects in the IDE).

Comment: ok.  So I can still stick with Ant which is familiar if I head down the Gradle path.

Comment: No, you can't use Ant with Gradle. You have to use Gradle to compile your app.